# Cufon to Font Face conversion

Tags: fonts, font-face, cufon, typography, webfonts

I work with different languages quite a lot and I have a font face file on a site I'm working on that doesn't support all the glyphs needed for that language. I do however have a cufon file of the same font that has these glyphs in and I would like to be able to use this file to create another font face file so it has all the glyphs I need.

Ideally I would have the original font file with all the glyphs in so I could just do it using font squirrel or whatever but that would bake my job far too easy :P

If anyone knows of a way to either convert a cufon file to font face or how to decompile cufon to give you back the original font that would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible due to font licensing issues. If such a tool existed, then it would be very easy to 'steal' fonts from other websites without paying for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boz Answered this in his comment,

> I'm pretty sure this isn't possible due to font licensing issues. If
>   such a tool existed, then it would be very easy to 'steal' fonts from
>   other websites without paying for them.

– boz Apr 30 at 16:21